# Is DB2 CLPPLUS editor able to do xquery

Tags: db2, clp, clpplus

I am new to the CLPPlus editor and I'm trying a simple query that works if I execute it from a file like this

```
db2 -td% -svf C:\query.sql
```

and the query.sql file contains:

```
SELECT tx.ID,XMLQUERY('for $e in $d/Client/Address return data($e)' passing tx.contactinfo as "d") FROM clients tx %
```

If I just place the query as it is in the CLP or CLPPLUS editor as it is I get errors.

> Error FROM CLP: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "for $e in $d/Client/Ad"
>   was found following "LECT tx.ID,XMLQUERY(".  Expected tokens may
>   include: "
>
> Error from CLPPLUS: SQL16002N  An XQuery expression has an unexpected
>   token "in" following "for ". Expected tokens may include: "is". Error
>   QName=err:XPST0003.

Comment: You may want to include a screenshot of how you "place the query in the editor". If you run that simply from the command line, you'll need to properly escape all quotes and other special characters.

Comment: Thanks for that input. I escaped the double quotes on the CLP and it works but when I ran the same query in the CLPPLUS it still did not work.